# Linux Mint: removing files via UI does not always delete the file icon from directory

Tags: files, linux-mint, delete

I'm using Linux Mint 18.3 (Cinnamon 3.6.7) and I've noticed that when I delete files using the 'Del' key, sometimes they do not disappear from the directory. If I try to delete them again, I get an error saying "no such file or directory". However, if I `cd` into the directory and run `ls`, they would no longer be there.

I've found an old discussion on this problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164026/unable-to-delete-file-no-such-file-or-directory) but the solutions were hacky and given the age of this discussion, I thought that there must be a better way to permanently avoid this problem. For anyone experiencing this problem, I can recommend a simple, temporary solution: create an empty file or folder with the same name as the file you are trying to delete and them remove it.

If anyone has any tips on how to resolve this issues, I'd love to hear from you.

Many thanks

Comment: @dsstorefile1, good question, how would I refresh the listings? Would I have to restart Cinnamon?

Comment: Yep, but that wouldn't work on desktop though